# Remove css class from primary tabs

Tags: drupal, tabs, drupal-7

By default, Drupal prints the primary tabs like this:

`<ul class="tabs--primary nav nav-tabs"></ul>`

Now I want to remove the `nav`class from the `<ul>`

I tried to insert this code in my template.php but without any luck:
http://pastebin.com/vkxkmCwS

Comment: Please give the resulting HTML from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Menu attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_attributes) module and apply [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/1862048#comment-9546609) to have an ability to edit classes of menu.

Or to override menu template, use `theme_menu_tree` in you template.php:

```
function themename_menu_tree($variables) {
  return '<ul class="menu my-class">' . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```